# CSS hide elements on popup

Tags: html, css

I'm new here and have a litte question.

I found this here and have some questions how it works and how I could change a litte thing:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: url(http://www.shukatsu-note.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/computer-564136_1280.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #06D85F;
  margin: 80px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #06D85F;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #06D85F;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Popup/Modal Windows without JavaScript</h1>
<div class="box">
 <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>Here i am</h2>
  <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  <div class="content">
   Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I had created a litte template for me.
On this script the overlay class change the background color when the popup is visible.

Could it possible to hide the background elements h1 and the box with css without change the background and without javascript?

To make it more clean, I want to hide the content behind the popup instead of .overlay { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }

Greetings, Dan

Comment: what do you mean by background elements.. they are already hidden with an overlay.. what exactly do you want please be more clear and specific.

Comment: Okay I try to make it more clear,

.overlay {
Set a new layer with a background.

But instead of the new background wich lay over I want to hide the content behind the popup.

I found something to hide / show items on checkboxes or buttons. But if this could be used with the popup I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

The whole effect is achieved by the fact that the `div.overlay` contains all the content to be displayed. The trick is:

- normally hide the container
- activate it by linking to it
- when referenced, show the container
- de-activate it by linking to something else.

This uses a relatively new CSS pseudo class called `:target`. The way it work is:

- the URL has a fragment identifier (`#something`)
- the element whose `id` matches the fragment gets the `:target` pseudoclass
- if the URL changes, then some other element may be targeted.

You will notice that two anchors are involved:

- to show the popup, the anchor has `#popup1`, where `popup1` is the id of the popup div
- to hide the popup, the anchor has `#`, which, most importantly, is *not* `#popup1`, so that div will no longer be targeted.

To answer the other part, using this technique, only content of the `div` can be hidden & shown, so if you want to hide or show other content, it won’t work this way. For that you will need JavaScript.

Comment: Okay best thanks, 

I had found a way to hide the content behind the popup and
had set the background image to the .overlay class instead the color. 
But it's good to know that the other ways won't work without javascript. :) best Thanks for the description